# Showing the column name only once in a loop

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I have a loop through a recordset named `rs1`.
When I'm displaying the results, I'm getting the following list of records:

```
January - 1245
January - 5487
January - 8547
January - 8987
January - 0247
February - 7854
February - 8541
February - 9321
February - 9001
February - 6658
```

The results of the recordset are correct and is exactly that I want, but as you can see, the month column is repeated continuously without reason. Is there any way to display the month name **ONLY ONCE** in the **first line** of my results like following?

```
January - 1245
        - 5487
        - 8547
        - 8987
        - 0247
February - 7854
         - 8541
         - 9321
         - 9001
         - 6658
```

The way that I'm doing the loop is as follows:

```
<%
Dim Repeat1__numRows
Dim Repeat1__index

Repeat1__numRows = -1
Repeat1__index = 0
rs1_numRows = rs1_numRows + Repeat1__numRows
%>

'Here is the display of the results

<% 
  Repeat1__index=Repeat1__index+1
  Repeat1__numRows=Repeat1__numRows-1
  rs1.MoveNext()
Wend
%>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like DO-WHILE loops, but you can use whatever loop you want, as all you need is a simple if statement.

```
dim strMonth, numTotals
Response.Write "<table>"
do while not rs1.EOF
   numTotals = rs("numTotals")
   Response.Write "<tr>"
   if strMonth <> rs("monthName") then 
       strMonth = rs1("monthName")
       Response.Write "<td>" & strMonth & "</td>"
   else
       Response.Write "<td>&nbsp;</td>"
   end if

   Response.Write "<td>" & numTotals & "</td>"
   Response.Write "</tr>"

   rs1.MoveNext
loop

Response.Write "</table>"
```